# Regular expression matching more than allowed characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to validate that the given string contains contains only letters, numbers, spaces, and characters from a set of symbols (`!-?():&,;+`).  Here is what I have so far:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 !-?\(\):&,;\+]+$/
```

Now this works somewhat but it accepts other characters as well.  For example, strings containing `*` or `#` validate.  I thought that the `^` at the beginning of the expression and the `$` at the end meant that it would match the whole string.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: At first glance, this should work.  Is it possible there is something going wrong in the rest of your code?  Can you post some of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 !-?\(\):&,;\+]+$/
```

The - is not nice where you placed it! If you want to place - inside a character class be sure to either place it **first** or **last** e.g.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 !?\(\):&,;\+-]+$/
```

Otherwise it will take the range of ! until ? whatever this range maybe...Depends on your regex machine.

Finally special characters are not special inside character classes. So no need to escape most of them :

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 !?():&,;+-]+$/
```

Comment: You can just escape the - inside a character class

Comment: @BenjaminUdinktenCate Yes but it is unecessary clutter.

Answer (score 2):

You have specified a "range" within your character class:

```
[!-?]
```

Means all ASCII symbols between `!` and `?`
http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

You need to escape the minus `-` with a `\` backslash. (OTOH the backslash is redundant before the `+` and `(` and `)` within a character class.)

Comment: Or you can put - as last or first character.

Comment: As mentioned on the linked page.